# how to send different commands to clustered terminals using cssh

Tags: terminal, command, send

How can I send different commands to multiple terminals each connected to a remote host.

Example: I have 20 terminals each connected to a remote host. I need to navigate to a directory in each terminal/remote host where the folder name available on each host is different from each other.

host1: cd user123
host2: cd user345
host3: cd user678
...
...

I am using csshx to control the multiple terminals on mac.